# Why wont counter_cache work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class FixedLineItem < AR

  belongs_to :fee_table, :class_name => 'FixedFeeTable',
                         :foreign_key => 'fixed_fee_table_id',
                         :inverse_of => :line_items,
                         :counter_cache => :fixed_line_items_count
end

class FixedFeeTable < AR

  has_many :line_items, :class_name => 'FixedLineItem', 
                        :inverse_of => :fee_table                         
end
```

Given the above, why does @fixed_fee_table.line_items.size still access the db? I can see it performing a COUNT operation in the console.

If i rename the has_many association to has_many :fixed_line_items, it works as expected.

Am i missing an option somewhere? I cant find any mention through googling however.

**EDIT**

This is on rails 3.2.14

and my schema for the two tables

```
create_table "fixed_fee_tables", :force => true do |t|
t.string  "kind"
t.integer "total_amount_cents"
t.integer "fee_summary_id"
t.string  "currency"
t.integer "final_total_amount_cents"
t.integer "fixed_line_items_count",   :default => 0, :null => false
end

create_table "fixed_line_items", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "description"
t.integer  "quantity"
t.integer  "price_cents"
t.integer  "fixed_fee_table_id"
t.datetime "created_at",             :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",             :null => false
t.integer  "amount_cents"
t.integer  "position"
t.integer  "total_adjustment_cents"
t.string   "currency"
```

end

Comment: Which rails version? I feel like it behaves a bit differently in rails4.

Comment: Sorry my bad - Rails 3.2.14

Comment: Can you show us your schemas?